# codeigniter template system problem

Tags: git, templates, codeigniter, github, project

Hello all i have a problem that i want to show 3 diffrent rows in my footer and 2 diffrent rows in my sidebar.. but how can i do that?

you can see my project here http://rapcom.dk/forside

i want to know the best way to do it, do i need to have a library for every "row" i want to show and the make a view file and make the setup and then load it with the template function
$this->template->write_view('footer', 'viewHere', $data); ??

you can see my project here on github https://github.com/SimonJ/hip-hop

hope you understand my bad english :)

Comment: Please don't point to ALL of your code on github and expect us to troll through it to find your problem for you.  Help us out here, you'll get better answers.  Why not show some code in your question?  The link to the problem page is helpful, but so would the associated code, like how `queryProfile` is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you're asking, but can't you provide an array of data when loading your footer view and then iterate through multiple rows inside of your footer view file?